# What is this thing called that holds the gear shift cable (not the wire)?

Tags: gears, cable-routing

There is a small metal part that keeps the gear shift cable in place, so the inside cable can move without the cable hose moving as well. I think I damaged it slightly when making repairs so I need a new one, but I have no idea how that part is called or if it is something specific to my bike. I have a Shimano Nexus 8 internal shifter.

I attached a photo of the part standalone and installed.

[image: part standalone]
[image: part installed]

Comment: My first thought was **Ferrule**, but that's a permanent crimp-on.  Your one is designed to be removed in the field for wheel removal, so it has to be sprung.   When you do find a replacement, consider how you can apply some super-glue to make it stay in the housing and not get damaged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its definitely a stop for the outer cable, allowing the inner cable to proceed.

On a shimano Alfine or Nexus IGH it is on the end of the Cassette Joint, part "CJ-S7000-8"  which is part of the "Alfine Small Parts Set" part nmber "SM-7000-8"

This kit is surprisingly not-too-expensive, considering the green/blue anti-rotation washers cost 1/4 of the whole kit cost each.

Note that the -8 suffix means for an 8 speed, a -11 suffix is the eleven speed.   I'm not sure if there is a different part for the Nexus vs the Alfine 8 - a good chance its the same part for both.

Comment: Any idea why this part is required in addition to a normal 4–5mm cable housing ferrule?

Comment: Because the whole cable has to be removed from the Cassette Joint to drop the wheel for a puncture, whereas a derailleur generally is cabled once and left until the inners/outers need replacing.  I was getting a puncture every 4-6 weeks (sometimes 2 in one ride)  and this little springy gidget came loose.  In a hurry, I jammed it into my pocket and rode on to work, and the shifting was awful.  At work in my break, I refitted the bit from my pocket, and shifting was much better.

Answer (score 6):

In Shimano-ese, it is part of the "Outer Receiving Unit." 
[image]
[image]

You can pull up the exploded view diagram for you specific hub model on techdocs.shimano.com to corroborate what you need. Then you can google around for "shimano outer receiving unit" and get the right part number for your hub on the off chance that it's different for the different Shimano internal hubs.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a "cable stop."

On most bikes with derailleurs, it is integral to the frame (welded, brazed, bonded, or riveted on). On your bike, it is part of the hub assembly.

There are clamp-on cable stops that would fit to your chainstay and might work here, but I think the better solution is to get an exact replacement part, which should be possible. Check with your local bike shop.

Comment: I believe that part is specific to the shimano internal gear hubs. You can order a kit of all the small parts for those hubs (including the part in question) here: https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=28406&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2-f_v-KN5wIVw56zCh2PJA9AEAQYAiABEgJFsfD_BwE

Comment: Thanks! Thats awesome.